# Disabling Many Controls Automatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a windows form with several buttons, text boxes, combo boxes, etc. At some point during execution, I disable all of them as follows:

```
Control01.Enabled = false;
Control02.Enabled = false;
Control03.Enabled = false;
// ...
Control10.Enabled = false;
```

How can I automate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enumerate controls and disable them:

```
foreach(var control in Controls.Cast<Control>())
   control.Enabled = false;
```

If you want to disable only buttons, you can use LINQ

```
foreach(var control in Controls.OfType<Button>())
   control.Enabled = false;
```

Or if you have some other criteria of selection

```
var controlsToDisable = Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                .Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith("Control")); // etc

foreach(var control in controlsToDisable)
   control.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: but note: `foreach (Button b in Controls)` is not equal to the LINQ Expression. (This is often seen, but it would result in trying to cast EVERY control to a "Button")

Comment: @dognose nope, there is method `Cast<Button>` which will try to cast all controls to button. `OfType<Button>` will return only those control which can be cast to button

Comment: And it might help to put those controls in an array if they're spread across the user-interface (e.g. not being inside single container, or are but with other controls that shouldn't be disabled).

Comment: For some reason, it is not recognizing the `Enabled` method. :-( http://oi44.tinypic.com/vdif0l.jpg

Comment: @JosuéMolina sorry, you need to cast to control type `Cast<Control>()` because by default enumerator will return objects. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `for` loop combined with the `Controls.Find()` method :

```
string controlIdNr ="";
for(int i=1;i++;i<11)
{
    controlIdNr = "Control" + i.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0');
    this.Controls.Find(controlIdNr,true).Enabled = false;
}
```

This is of course if your controls have a structured id value. If you want to disable all controls, or all controls of a given type, lazyberezovsky's answer is better !

P.S : I haven't tested code, but that's the idea anyway...

Comment: @lazyberezovsky > indeed ! I editted my answer. I'm more a ASP.NET guy and FindControl() only requires the control's id ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If your layout allows it, you can put them on a panel and disable the panel in one line. Or maybe several few panels.